# How to avoid loosing complex query in a view?

Tags: caml-query, view

In a custom list definition bound to a custom content type, I attached the out of the box `AssignedTo` field.

In the schema, I defined a view with this query :

```
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified"
                  Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
      <Where>
        <Or>
          <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
          </Membership>
          <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
            <Value Type="Integer">
              <UserID />
            </Value>
          </Eq>
        </Or>
      </Where>
    </Query>
```

The idea of this view is to display items either if the current user is specified in the AssignedTo field, or if the user is member of the group specified in the field.

This is working as expected. However, as soon as I change something in the view settings with the browser, the query is broken. It seems that the web UI does not know how to interpret my custom query, and override it when I save.

How can I avoid this settings page to break my query? is there a better way to display direct assignation or indirect assignation in the same view ?